# Symfony2: slow write to S3 from EC2 instance

Tags: symfony, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I have 1 micro instance and S3 server for dev purposes within same region. My program has `typeahead` functionality that is working this way:

when user types "lond", the url is:

`mys3.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/typeahead/cities/lond.json`

Because it will return 404, javascript then tries:

`http://mydomain.com/typeahead/cities/lond.json`

This will trigger the controller that will find all cities starting with `lond`, write it to S3 and return json results.

So next time someone types "lond", results would be found on S3 as static file and no controller action will be executed.

Now all this works but the problem is that I have very slow write speed from EC2 to S3. When I remove

```
$filesystem->write($filename, json_encode($results), true) ;
```

from my code, the response is ~0.7 seconds. With writting to S3, it goes to 2 seconds which is hardly usefull. The problem is bigger for fast typers, probably because of quick writes sent to S3.

I am using KnpGaufretteBundle.

I also tried

```
echo json_encode($results);
$filename->write(....) ;
die;
```

to send output to browser and after that continue to save file to S3 but it didn't work. JS didn't get response earlier.

ob_start(), ob_end_flush().... and others didn't work either.

How can I solve it?

I was thinking of starting some background process that will upload result (although, I don't know how to do it) but I think it would be just too complicated.

The other idea is to use `amazon_s3` service directly and skip KnpGaufretteBundle, but I would like to avoid that.

Answer (score 0):

What you seem to be trying to do, is use s3 to store cached data that is better stored in memcached or another memory based store.

I'll give you a couple of other options. You could use both if you wanted, but 1 is more than enough.

1. Use memcached (redis or another key value store) with read through caching. You will use one end point, which on a request, will check if the value exists in the cache, then will read through to get the result if it does not. At the same time, the result will be stored in the cache.
2. Use a cloudfront distribution with a custom origin. The custom origin will be your website.  With this option, the result will be cached on a cloudfront endpoint for a duration specified by your headers. Each endpoint may check the source for the file if it does not have it. To prevent the custom origin from accidentally caching the wrong stuff, you may want to check for the cloudfront user agent and allow it to only access certain urls.

Comment: Thanks, although I hardly understood anything :) What I wanted is to completelly skip controller execution if the cached file already exists. Will your solution do that and if you have some link with examples? Thanks.

Comment: Using cloudfront with a custom origin would do exactly that. The cache on cloudfront will eventually expire, but you can increase the time cached by sending a long expiration header with the request.